# How can I fix th Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I use HTTPService to send a request to a web-service. the web-service runs a query in SQL Server and brings back a row set f data as in XML format. the service is working fine as long as there is no blank in the title of any column in the result set. However if there is any space (blank) inside of a column name (like "Customer Name"), I encounter the following error:

> Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.

Using HTTPFox addon in FireFox, I can see that the records retrieved as it's displayed below. I think this the problem is the blank in the XML tags which is retrieved by the service.

```
    <record>
            <Year><![CDATA[2009]]></Year>
            <Owner><![CDATA[BLM]]></Owner>
            <Customer Name><![CDATA[Smith Naval]]></Customer Name>
    </record>
```

Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what to tell that you don't seem to already know.

You can't have spaces in an XML tag and still be XML compliant.  Many would argue that a database shouldn't have spaces in column names too.

If possible, I would replace the spaces in the database columns with an underscore.  If that isn't possible, I would perform some server side processing when creating your XML so that spaces don't appear in the XML tag name.

Here are a few options:

1. Name the tag using every letter up to, but not including, the first space of the column name
2. Remove the spaces in the tag names while generating the XML.
3. Process your returned value as text.  To me this sounds very difficult; but if you're up on Regex may be possible.